# Freeze deserializing NotifyPropertyChanged aspect

Tags: postsharp

We use Postsharp to automate the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation in our WPF application. It works great but at startup, we have a UI freeze deserializing aspects.

[See visual studio call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B64BN.png)

The duration of the freeze is variable. It varies from 3 seconds to 25 seconds.
If I remove the NotifyPropertyChanged aspect on the base class of our viewmodels, the application starts instantly without freeze.

I can't control the deserialization moment (deserialization starts when the first occurence of an aspect is met) and it seems I can't change the serialization mecanism of the NotifyPropertyChanged aspect provided by Postsharp.

It is problematic for us because it locks the login page. Our version of Postharp is 5.0.45.0.

Is there a workaround to avoid this kind of freeze ? Does anyone know a solution to that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We didn't yet run into an issue with deserialization taking so much time. Since the deserialization starts when you first access an enhanced type, as a workaround you can avoid using any enhanced types on the login page. We would need to do more investigation to find out the cause. What is the number of classes enhanced by PostSharp in your project? Did you try upgrading to the latest PostSharp version?

Comment: I investigated deeper last week. The executable file size is 24 Mb activating the Postsharp NotifyPropertyChanged aspect, 3 Mb without. 
I have seen that the NotifyPropertyChanged aspect intercepts not only property setters, but also property getters, methods and events for dependency analysis.
We have a huge application. It seems that the Postsharp NotifyPropertyChanged aspect is too expensive for us. I have implemented my own NotifyPropertyChanged aspect without dependency analysis. I manually manage dependencies now. The executable file is 4 Mb and the application start is instant.